# Create reversed mxHierarchical layout in mxgraph

Tags: javascript, mxgraph, jgraphx, jgraph

Greetings to the community! I am currently creating a custom mxgraph editor and I am converting the graphs using different layouts. I would like to convert my graph layout into an `mxHierarchicalLayout` but **reversed** (instead of `top-to-down` I would like it to be `down-to-top`). Example of what I do and what I would like to do.

**My graph**

[image: my graph]

**My graph converted with mxHierarchicalLayout**
Code snippet:

`let layout = new mxHierarchicalLayout(graph);
layout.execute(graph.getDefaultParent());`

[image: my graph with mxhierarchicallayout]

**How I want to convert the graph**

[image]

I found in the mxHierarchicalLayout that there is an `orientation` member variable which is by default 'NORTH'. However when I tried to do the following

```
 let layout = new mxHierarchicalLayout(graph);
 layout.orientation=mxConstants.DIRECTION_SOUTH;
 layout.execute(graph.getDefaultParent());
```

The graph went out of my "canvas" and cannot be seen to check if this is the responsible parameter to "reverse" the tree. Could anyone help ? Thanks in advance.

**PS**

When I use `layout.orientation = mxConstants.DIRECTION_SOUTH;`
it seems that the layout is converted as I want to but cannot be seen because the coordinates of the svg elements are of `type x=-10, y=-5 (negatives)`, any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I do not know why mxgraph has that buggy behaviour with `orientation = south` in mxHierarchicalLayout but I managed to create a workaround solution for my problem since I realized that the newly generated layout put my mxCell children objects  of the graph to the north  ( negative y coordinate). So what I did was after `layout.execute(graph.getDefaultParent());` I get each and every child of the graph and retrieve the most negative y coordinate and then move all the cells of the graph from their new coordinates to a new incremented by the absolute value of the most negative y-coordinated element.

**Code**

```
 function convertGraphToInverseHorizontalTree(){
        let layout = new mxHierarchicalLayout(graph);
        layout.orientation = mxConstants.DIRECTION_SOUTH;
        layout.execute(graph.getDefaultParent());
        graph.model.beginUpdate();
        //get the most negative y
        let mostNegativeY = getMostNegativeCoordinateY(graph);
        let children = graph.getChildCells();
        graph.moveCells(children, undefined , Math.abs(mostNegativeY));
        graph.model.endUpdate();
    }

    function getMostNegativeCoordinateY(graph){
        let children = graph.getChildCells();
        let mostNegative = 10000;
        for(let i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
           if(children[i].geometry != undefined){
               if(children[i].geometry.y < mostNegative){
                   mostNegative = children[i].geometry.y;
                   }
           }
        }
        return mostNegative;
    }
```

Now the graph is like this

[image: inversed hierarchical tree]